# Modeling multiple-choice data

Tags: logistic, multiple-regression, reinforcement-learning, decision-theory

In my experiment, participants had to make a series of decisions between different options. On each trial, they were presented with a different number of options to choose from, and each option varied along two dimensions: d1 and d2. For example, on trial t, a participant could be given the choice between [(d1:5, d2:2), (d1:2, d2:24), (d1:16, d2:-2)], and then on trial t+1 between [(d1:9, d2:1), (d1:7, d2:6)]. There is no relation between the first option on trial t and the first option on trial t+1. They only select one option per trial.

I am trying to determine how much participants cared about d1 and d2 when making their decisions. One way to approach this is to model the decision as choosing the noisy maximum among $\beta_1 d_1+\beta_2 d_2$, and finding the beta values that maximize the likelihood of the participants' decisions. However, I wonder if there is a simpler statistical method that I am overlooking. Thanks!

Comment: It depends on the experimental design, but it appears you are trying to estimate *indifference curves.*  Would that be correct?  And, if so, would this be a set of curves for the population or a separate set of curves for each participant?  And again, if this is a correct interpretation, do you make any assumptions about these curves, such as linearity?  Do you examine the results for consistency in responses among each participant?

Comment: Thanks! I'm not sure indifference curves are the right outcome for me: ideally I would like to get something like coefficients for each dimension, such that I can compare them across experimental conditions and participants. An interesting finding, for example, would be whether subjects are more sensitive to d1 in condition 1 compared to condition 2.

Comment: Indifference curves are a standard way to find those coefficients.  See Keeney & Raiffa, *Decisions with Multiple Objectives.*